# Filtering with setAllFilters in react-table version 7

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using the new hooks version of react-table. I have data like this:

```
data: const persons = [{name: 'Ram', age: 15 }, {name: 'Shyam', 
age: 18 }, {name: 'Hari', age: 20 }]
```

I would like to filter the persons by age. I used `setAllFilters()` function to filter.

For filtering persons whose age is 15,

```
setAllFilters({age: 15})
```

just works.

However, I would like to filter all the persons whose age is 15 or 18. How would it be possible ?

Comment: Could you provide how you implement this `setAllFilters({age: 15})?
 `

Comment: @NarendraJadhav You can use setAllFilters in componentDidMount or useEffect if you are using hooks. But, first you need to destructure the react table instance  to get setAllFilters function as below: const {setAllFilters} = useTable(useFilters); You need to import useTable and useFilters from react-table.